# my button doesnt trigger as should and instead gives two errors (before and after click)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, error-handling, unity-ui

hello I have a button plus a box which alpha is 0 from the start, the button works but the box doesn't appear. In the code the I did use 'getcontents' but it seems it didn't work, the button executes a debug.log so that's how I know that is working, the errors I get before the button click is;
[before button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YLwz.png)

and the errors after button click (including the debug.log)
[after button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jDqA.png)

it says i haven't attached my 'Menuee' although i have (yes i know i spelt it like that)
show here;

[attached Menuee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT8Mz.png)

and i have attached my Ibutton (the button)

my code is below;

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class startbutton : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button Ibutton;
    public CanvasGroup Menuee;

    public void Start () {
        
        Ibutton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }
    public void TaskOnClick(){
        Debug.Log ("yes");
        
        Menuee.interactable= true;
        Menuee.alpha = 1;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

In the screen shot you don't seem to have anything assigned to `Button Ibutton`.

Another reason for such errors could be that you might have assigned the `startbutton` script to another game object somewhere and that instance of the script doesn't have the properties assigned.

Comment: so i cant have two game objects with the same script? how can i effect other game objects from inside one?

Comment: Dude thank you that helped so much its working now!!!

Comment: Of course you can have more than one object with the same script but each one of them needs to have its properties assigned separately.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add a button on your `public Button Ibutton;`
You might also some how delete EventManager that comes with canvas you created on hierarch window.